# Load visible and invisible products at once?

Tags: product, collection, product-collection, magento-1, collection-filtering

This is my code:

```
$visibility = array(
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG,
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE
);

 $_productCollection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')
    ->load($_categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility);
```

I want to get all products, no matter what visibility they have. The code above skips those that are not visible though. Whats wrong? Is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 5):

The method `getProductCollection()` of the category model already applies some filters. If you look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::_applyProductLimitations()` you will see that the visibility filter is part of a join condition that joins the category with `catalog/category_product_index`, but is only applied if `isset($filters['visibility'])`. You define this filter with `setVisibility()`, so to remove the filter you can use:

```
$_productCollection->setVisibility(null);
```

Or to filter explicitly for the possible values:

```
$_productCollection->setVisibility(array(
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG,
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE
);
```

Comment: I think it is only for magento1. Not working in magento2. Please give example for mangento2 as well.

Comment: This is an old question, tagged as Magento 1. Magento 2 is so different that it would deserve a new question

Comment: I have created a new question. please help me out if possible. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199721/visible-and-invisible-products-are-not-showing-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Remove the visibility filter:  `->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)`.

Use this:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')
    ->load($_categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: That gives me only the visible ones.

Comment: it loads the category resource model which filters out the not visible products