# Production collection remove visibility filter

Tags: product, blocks, collection, product-collection, custom-collection

I'd like to load products by IDs, but ignore the product visibility. So when loading a product collection I'd like to even have products in the collection that have visibility "Search".

On a related note: I am using a custom Catalog Block extending `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` so I can get the product list by calling

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_xyz')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')
```

Inside my custom catalog type block I'm using `Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);` Is there any way to "reset" the visibility filter?

Comment: There is no way to reset visibility filter on collection class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is related to [collection - Load visible and invisible products at once](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40680/load-visible-and-invisible-products-at-once).

To reset the visiblity filter, try this:

```
$_productCollection->setVisibility(null);
```

You can change the filter using the following code:

```
$_productCollection->setVisibility(array(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG,
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE
);
```

Comment: Using `$_productCollection->setVisibility(null);` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: I think it is only for magento1. Not working in magento2. Please give example for mangento2 as well.