# visible and invisible products are not showing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-collection

Inspired by answer mentioned in the [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40680/load-visible-and-invisible-products-at-once). I wrote following code but it is not returning **invisible** products.

```
$productCollection = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId())
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->setVisibility(null)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
```

Comment: Have you tried re-indexing ?

Comment: You can check with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80179/magento-2-apply-visibility-and-status-filters-on-product-collection

Comment: yes but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**it is not possible in magento2.**

In the back end, following query is getting executed.

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.visibility IN(4, 2, 1)
```

If we mark a product as invisible, magento2 is removing from `catalog_category_product_index` so regardless of `visibility` filter, inner join will not work. Further you can see that `visibility` field is inside `catalog_category_product_index` table.

**way around**

In my case no category filter was required so I used following code.

```
$productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
```